# ASP.Net MVC 3: Where to handle session loss?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-timeout

I've started bumping into errors when my session has been lost, or upon rebuilding my project, as my forms authentication cookie still lives on.

In WebForms I'd use the masterpage associated with pages which require login to simply check for the session.

How would I do this in one location in MVC ? I'd hate having to check for session state in every action in my controllers.

On the other hand I can't just apply a global filter either, since not all Controllers require session state.

Would it perhaps be possible in my layout view ? It's the only thing the pages which require session have in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to sub-class the controllers that do need session state. This way you could create a filter on just this base controller. This would allow you to do it all in one place.  Plus, as you pointed out, a global filter won't help you here since the logic does not apply to every controller.

Comment: +1 This seems like a good idea, however does the controller have a central point of entry which I can check in ? (For my base controller)

Comment: @Steffen - your goal is to keep it DRY and only have the logic in your code once. So you create a base controller that you inherit from *only* for the ones where this functionality is needed. You then apply the filter to the class declaration of this controller so that it's run for all action methods that the controller (or any of its sub-classes) execute.

Answer (score 2):

add it to session start. if a session loss happens it needs to trigger a session start too. you can handle it in there as follows:

```
protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null)
        {
            if (Context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sCookieHeader) && (sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    // how to simulate it ???   
                    // RedirectToAction(“ActionName”, “ControllerName”,  route values);  
                    Response.Redirect("/Home/TestAction");
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Steve has mentioned, but I suggest to use Global Filters instead of creating a base class for all your controllers. The reason for this is everytime you create a new controller, you should always remember to derive from the base controller or you may experience random behaviours in your application that may take you hours of debugging. This is especially important when you stop development for a while and then get back to it.

Also, another reason is the "Favour composition over inheritance" principle.